# C# - Conversão de tempo - Qual seria a solução?

Tags: c#

Você terá o desafio de ler um valor inteiro, que é o tempo de duração em segundos de um determinado evento em uma loja, e informe-o expresso no formato horas:minutos:segundos.

```
using System;

    class MinhaClasse {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var timeInSeconds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       //continue a solucao
            var hours = ;
            timeInSeconds =  ;
            var minutes =   ;
            var seconds =    ;

            Console.WriteLine($"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `TimeSpan` e converter o `inteiro` em segundos para um horário

```
        var completeTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeInSeconds);


        //continue a solucao
        var hours = completeTime.Hours;
        var minutes = completeTime.Minutes;
        var seconds = completeTime.Seconds;
```

Input: `123123`
Output: `10:12:3`

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: O objetivo do site não é fazer a tarefa de casa dos usuários. Ao fazer isso você não está ajudando a pessoa.

Comment: Eu concordo, mas infelizmente eu preciso de pelos menos 50 pontos de reputação para adicionar comentários em uma pergunta, é isso que estou tentando fazer rsrs